# PHP Shorthand for Pre-Concatenation?

Tags: php, string, concatenation

I've been programming in PHP for years, and I've always wondered if there is a way to 'pre-concatenate' a string. Example:

```
$path = '/lib/modules/something.php';
$server = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

I've been doing this for years in order to append a value to the beginning of a string:

```
$path = $server . $path;
// returns: /home/somesite.com/public_html/lib/modules/something.php
```

Is there a shorthand for this? Just curious.

Comment: By shorthand do you mean along the lines of .= as you would do if you wanted to append instead of prepend?

Answer (score 6):

A not so serious answer (I know it's longer):

```
$path = strrev($path);
$path .= strrev($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$path = strrev($path);
```

There is no limit to creativity! ;)

Answer (score 3):

a shorthand for concatenation is [interpolation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing):

```
  $path = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/lib/modules/something.php";
```

Comment: But interpolation does only work with literal strings and variables.

Comment: I rather meant that a literal string declaration is needed to concatenate variables. And you can only use variables and no other value returning expressions like functions calls etc.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you could write your own function:

```
function pc(&$a, &$b) {
    $a = $b . $a;
}
pc($path, $server);
```

The above call to `pc` will set `$path` to `$server . $path`.

Comment: A function like this is just a suggestion for a shorthand, as there is no in-built syntax for this. If you don't like it, don't use it...?

Comment: Actually you wrote a method of a class. Still I agree with Gumbo on this one.

Comment: This is the only real shorthand answer, though. I'm not saying it's necessarily good or bad to use, but OP wanted a shorthand, and I wrote one.

Answer (score 0):

try out the sprintf function as it has worked for me - information on it here: http://docs.php.net/sprintf

Comment: This just makes it longer, unfortunately.